# Simulate redirect_to with remote option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following scheme:
**lessons_controller** -> **show.html.erb**, which contains *form_tag* with *remote: true* -> **test_controller** -> **show.js** -> **_test.html.erb**

So I receive the content of **_test.html.erb** when submit the form_tag on **lesson/show** page.

But I want to skip the **lesson/show** page in some cases.

So I want to go to the **lesson/show** page and receive the content of **_test.html.erb** without submitting anything, under the ground. Something like **redirect_to** in **lessons_controller** with **remote** option to simulate the form_tag submitting.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your purpose, if you only want to show the form directly, it's as simple as putting following in js assets

```
$ ->
  $(form#show_lesson).submit()
```

If you want to control it in controller level. You can do the following.

```
# Lessons controller
def show
  @lesson = Lesson.find params[:id]
  template = params[:show_directly].present? ? 'show' : 'show_with_test'
  render template
end

# views/show.html.erb
render partial: 'show_form'

# views/show_with_test.erb
render partial: 'test', locals: {lesson: @lesson}
```

Use

Browse `lessons/1` will show original form

Browse `lessons/1?show_directly=1` will show all directly.

Comment: Thanks, Billy. I thought about this solution. But the issue is I have a lot of logic in test_controller. If I will render test partial directly from lesson controller I need to duplicate this logic in lesson controller. I don't want that, so I'd want to redirect to test controller to run all this logic and after that render the test partial.

Comment: Alex, I still don't know your purpose, when you need to render full and why? Without these it's hard to suggest. And I would suggest you to use something other than 'test' if for a bit more complex case.

Comment: Say, if a visitor need submit form, but a signed in user can see all, that's a different case which should be set at authority. So different purpose decides solution.

Comment: I show lesson page in common case and it has remote submit form to go to the test after learning lesson. 
But I want to skip learning lesson page (and show test) if I call lesson with repeat param.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just invoke javascript submit when lessons#show is loaded, and use the callback data from _test.html.erb.

I don't think it's possible and good way to make a redirect request with a 'script' type.